# Kotlin string replace function not working for me?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hello everyone please help me i am try to modify link but it's not working. it's working on java but recently i convert java to kotlin and getting this error.

am trying to change my link [http://www.offertoro.com/click_track/api?offer_id=419393&pub_id=14&pub_app_id=5&USER_ID=[USER_ID]&GAID=[your_GAID]](http://www.offertoro.com/click_track/api?offer_id=419393&pub_id=14&pub_app_id=5&USER_ID=%5BUSER_ID%5D&GAID=%5Byour_GAID%5D) in [USER_ID] with current login user email but getting error.

Check Screenshot
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81cqA.png)

**Error**

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
CharSequence.replace(Regex, String) defined in kotlin.text
String.replace(String, String, Boolean = ...) defined in kotlin.text
```

**My code**

```
  fun modifyOfferLink() {
       val id = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email
        // Modifying Offer Link Acording to Offer Partner
        when (partner) {
            "ogads" -> Finallink = link + "&aff_sub5=" + mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email
            "offertoro" -> Finallink = link.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
            "none" -> {
                Finallink = link!!.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
            }
            else -> Finallink = link.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
        }
    }
```

OfferActivity.kt

```
package com.sgamer.creditsk.Activity

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams
import com.sgamer.creditsk.Activity.AndyConstants.ServiceType
import com.sgamer.creditsk.Activity.OfferDetailsActivity
import com.sgamer.creditsk.R
import com.sgamer.creditsk.Utils.*
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject

class OfferDetailsActivity constructor() : AppCompatActivity() {
    var Finallink: String? = null
    var package_id: String? = null
    var uniq_id: String? = null
    var offerid: String? = null
    var app_name: String? = null
    var description: String? = null
    var icon_url: String? = null
    var bg_image_url: String? = null
    var amount: String? = null
    var OriginalAmount: String? = null
    var link: String? = null
    var partner: String? = null
    var insTitle: String? = null
    var first_text: String? = null
    var second_text: String? = null
    var third_text: String? = null
    var fourth_text: String? = null
    var webview: Boolean? = null
    var ClickId: String? = null
    var ctx: OfferDetailsActivity? = null
    var later: TextView? = null
    var status_image: ImageView? = null
    var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    private val bannerAdManager: BannerAdManager_SK? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer_details)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        val adContainer: LinearLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.adView) as LinearLayout
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val bannerAdManager_SK: BannerAdManager_SK = BannerAdManager_SK(this@OfferDetailsActivity, adContainer)
        bannerAdManager_SK.BannerAds()
        ctx = this
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        getSupportActionBar()!!.setTitle(R.string.offer_details)
        getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        getSupportActionBar()!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)))
        getSupportActionBar()!!.setElevation(0f)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
        }
        changeStatusBarColor()
        initViews()
        modifyOfferLink()
    }

    private fun changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val window: Window = getWindow()
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }

    fun initViews() {
        val title: TextView = findViewById(R.id.title)
        val desc: TextView = findViewById(R.id.description)
        val instructionsTitle: TextView = findViewById(R.id.instructions)
        val first: TextView = findViewById(R.id.first)
        val second: TextView = findViewById(R.id.second)
        val third: TextView = findViewById(R.id.third)
        val fourth: TextView = findViewById(R.id.fourth)
        val des: TextView = findViewById(R.id.des)
        val complete_button: TextView = findViewById(R.id.complete_button)
        val button: TextView = findViewById(R.id.button)
        later = findViewById(R.id.later)
        val comSpace: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.comSpace)
        val offer_icon: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.offer_icon)
        val bg_image: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.bg_image)
        status_image = findViewById(R.id.status_image)
        uniq_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("uniq_id")
        offerid = getIntent().getStringExtra("offerid")
        app_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("app_name")
        package_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("package_id")
        description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description")
        icon_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("icon_url")
        bg_image_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("bg_image_url")
        amount = getIntent().getStringExtra("amount")
        OriginalAmount = getIntent().getStringExtra("OriginalAmount")
        link = getIntent().getStringExtra("link")
        partner = getIntent().getStringExtra("partner")
        first_text = getIntent().getStringExtra("first_text")
        insTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("instructionsTitle")
        second_text = getIntent().getStringExtra("second_text")
        third_text = getIntent().getStringExtra("third_text")
        fourth_text = getIntent().getStringExtra("fourth_text")
        webview = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("webview", false)
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("description")) {
            des.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("description"))
        } else {
            des.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("description"))
        }
        title.setText(app_name)
        desc.setText(getString(R.string.earn) + " " + amount + " " + getString(R.string.app_currency) + " " + getString(R.string.on_this_offer))
        Glide.with(this).load(icon_url)
                .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image).error(R.drawable.placeholder_image))
                .into(offer_icon)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            comSpace.setElevation(20f)
        }
        instructionsTitle.setText(insTitle)
        first.setText(first_text)
        second.setText(second_text)
        third.setText(third_text)
        fourth.setText(fourth_text)
        complete_button.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.complete_offer))
        if (!bg_image_url!!.isEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(this).load(bg_image_url).into(bg_image)
        } else {
        }

        // On click Listners
        later!!.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            public override fun onClick(view: View) {
                finish()
            }
        })
        complete_button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            public override fun onClick(view: View) {
                if (!App.isVPNConnected()) {
                    addoffer(amount, app_name + " Offer Credit", offerid)
                }
                AppUtils.parse(this@OfferDetailsActivity, Finallink)
            }
        })
        button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            public override fun onClick(view: View) {
                val launchIntent: Intent? = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage((package_id)!!)
                startActivity(launchIntent)
            }
        })
        isAppExist
        if (isAppExist) {
            complete_button.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        } else {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            complete_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }
    }

    fun addoffer(points: String?, Activity: String?, offerid: String?) {
        val client: AsyncHttpClient = AsyncHttpClient()
        val params: RequestParams = RequestParams()
        val jsObj: JsonObject = Gson().toJsonTree(API()) as JsonObject
        jsObj.addProperty("method_name", "user_offeradd")
        jsObj.addProperty("offer_id", offerid)
        jsObj.addProperty("email", mAuth!!.getCurrentUser()!!.getEmail())
        jsObj.addProperty("points", points)
        jsObj.addProperty("firebase_id", mAuth!!.getCurrentUser()!!.getUid())
        jsObj.addProperty("Activity", Activity)
        params.put("data", API.toBase64(jsObj.toString()))
        client.post(Javaaescipher.decrypt(), params, object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            public override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, responseBody: ByteArray) {
                Log.d("Response", String(responseBody))
                val res: String = String(responseBody)
                try {
                    val jsonObject: JSONObject = JSONObject(res)
                    val jsonArray: JSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ANDROID_REWARDS_APP")
                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val `object`: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val success: String = `object`.getString("success")
                        val msg: String = `object`.getString("msg")
                        if ((success == "1")) {
//                            Toast.makeText(OfferDetailsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
//                            Toast.makeText(OfferDetailsActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            public override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, responseBody: ByteArray, error: Throwable) {
                Log.d("error", error.toString())
            }
        })
    }

    private val isAppExist: Boolean
        private get() {
            val pm: PackageManager = getPackageManager()
            try {
                val info: PackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo((package_id)!!, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }

    fun modifyOfferLink() {
       val id = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email
        // Modifying Offer Link Acording to Offer Partner
        when (partner) {
            "ogads" -> Finallink = link + "&aff_sub5=" + mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email
            "offertoro" -> Finallink = link!!.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
            "none" -> {
                Finallink = link!!.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
            }
            else -> Finallink = link!!.replace("[USER_ID]", mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to figure out whats going on with the information you provide. Please add more information like what is link, example input format etc.

Comment: http://offers.in/open.php?id=[USER_ID]&offer_id=123 i want to replace [USER_ID] with email id

Comment: what does ````mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email```` return? I think it is not a string.

Comment: mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email current login user with firebase google

Comment: [Edit] your question to include where you've declared `link`.

Comment: @HenryTwist i am updated with more details please help me

Comment: They're not the details I asked for, I'm looking for where you declared `link` in your code. So `link = ...`.

Comment: @HenryTwist     var link: String? = null                                                                             
   link = getIntent().getStringExtra("link")

Comment: @HenryTwist i passed link by adapter

Comment: It seems that either `link` or `mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email` are not of String type

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko i am added full offerActivity.kt code please check

Comment: In that case `mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email` must be nullable?

Comment: Yes I've just checked, the email is nullable, so you'll either have to handle that case or assert it. This question should probably be closed as a typo @NikolaiShevchenko?

Comment: @HenryTwist if i save current login user email in shared preferences and use instead of `mAuth!!.currentUser!!.email` it's work?

Comment: Well it works now? That wouldn't change the problem at all. Maybe do some research on what nullable means in Kotlin, it's not something to work around, you should consider the case that it could be null.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely there is no sub-string that is exactly `[USER_ID]`. Are you sure is it not `["USER_ID"]` ?

Can you print the value of `link` before you call the replace. This may let us and you see the problem.

Comment: Example link http://www.offertoro.com/click_track/api?offer_id=419393&pub_id=14&pub_app_id=5&USER_ID=[USER_ID]&GAID=[your_GAID]

Comment: That should work. What is the value of `Finallink` ?

Comment: Getting error on complie e: F:\23\new_app\app\src\main\java\com\sgamer\creditsk\Activity\OfferDetailsActivity.kt: (238, 40): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
@InlineOnly public inline fun CharSequence.replace(regex: Regex, replacement: String): String defined in kotlin.text
public fun String.replace(oldValue: String, newValue: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): String defined in kotlin.text

Comment: Check screenshot https://res.cloudinary.com/dbgdthuyi/image/upload/v1617880486/Capture_fyetcu.png